# sum td value in table with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table in my program, which adds the values to that row
How can I add the third value of each row?

```js
$(".add-row").click(function() {
  var packageid = $('#pack').find(':selected').attr('data-id');
  var itemid = $('#itemname').find(':selected').attr('item-id');
  var itemname = $("#itemname").val();
  var item_price = $("#item_price").val();
  var packs = $("#pack").val();
  var markup = "<tr><td data-id=" + packageid + ">" + packs + "<td item-id=" + itemid + ">" + itemname + "</td><td class='price'>" + item_price + "</td><td><button class='btn btn-danger' id='del'>Delete</button></td></tr>";
  $("table tbody").append(markup);
});

$("table").on("click", "#del", function() {
  $("table tbody").find('tr td').each(function() {
    $("table").on("click", "#del", function() {
      $(this).parents("tr").remove();
    })
  });
});

$('.add-row').click(function() {

  var ids = [];
  $('.table tbody tr').each(function() {
    ids.push({
      packageid: $(this).find('td:nth-child(1)').attr('data-id'),
      itemid: $(this).find('td:nth-child(2)').attr('item-id'),
      item_price: $(this).find('td:nth-child(3)').html(),
    });

  });
  $('#demo').val(JSON.stringify(ids));
});
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <select class="form-control" id="pack" required>

      <option data-id="1" value="test">test</option>

    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <select class="form-control" id="itemname">

      <option item-id="1" value="test">example</option>

    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="item_price" placeholder="Price">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <button type="button" class="add-row btn btn-success cusb btn-anim"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i><span class="btn-text">Add Item</span></button>
  </div>
</form>

<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Package Name</th>
      <th>Item Name</th>
      <th>Item Price</th>
      <th>Delete</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>

  </tbody>
</table>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

I want to add items within the item's price and show it somewhere for example a div tag or span tag.
In this example, the third child of each scroll row should be added together and sum them together

Comment: Could you please elaborate more what exactly you want ? What do you mean by third value of each row ?

Comment: I want to get together with each time you click on the Add Row button to add values that are in the third row sum, the price, and then they are spilled elsewhere.

Comment: Can you elaborate with an example? What should be output?

Comment: I want to have a total of the td item price. The question is clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Updated** code by writing 'sum' logic in separate function.

```js
function calculateSum() {
    //Calculate sum of price
    var sum = 0;
    $('.table tbody tr').each(function() {
        var item_price = parseInt($(this).find('td:nth-child(3)').html());
        //Check for NaN & add.
        sum += item_price?item_price:0;
    });

    //Display to div
    $("#total").text(sum);
}

$(".add-row").click(function() {
    var packageid = $('#pack').find(':selected').attr('data-id');
    var itemid = $('#itemname').find(':selected').attr('item-id');
    var itemname = $("#itemname").val();
    var item_price = $("#item_price").val();
    var packs = $("#pack").val();
    var markup = "<tr><td data-id=" + packageid + ">" + packs + "<td item-id=" + itemid + ">" + itemname + "</td><td class='price'>" + item_price + "</td><td><button class='btn btn-danger' id='del'>Delete</button></td></tr>";
    $("table tbody").append(markup);
});

$("table").on("click", "#del", function() {
    $("table tbody").find('tr td').each(function() {
        $("table").on("click", "#del", function() {
            $(this).parents("tr").remove();
            calculateSum(); //Perform sum after removing row.
        })
    });
});

$('.add-row').click(function() {
    var ids = [];
    $('.table tbody tr').each(function() {
        ids.push({
            packageid: $(this).find('td:nth-child(1)').attr('data-id'),
            itemid: $(this).find('td:nth-child(2)').attr('item-id'),
            item_price: $(this).find('td:nth-child(3)').html(),
        });

    });

    calculateSum(); //Perform sum after adding row.

    $('#demo').val(JSON.stringify(ids));
});
```

```html
<form>
   <div class="col-md-3">
      <select class="form-control" id="pack" required>
         <option data-id="1" value="test">test</option>
      </select>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-3">
      <select class="form-control" id="itemname">
         <option item-id="1" value="test">example</option>
      </select>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-3">
      <input type="number" class="form-control" id="item_price" placeholder="Price">
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-3">
      <button type="button" class="add-row btn btn-success cusb btn-anim"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i><span class="btn-text">Add Item</span></button>
   </div>
</form>
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th>Package Name</th>
         <th>Item Name</th>
         <th>Item Price</th>
         <th>Delete</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
   </tbody>
</table>
<div id="total"></div>
<script
   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
   integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: This doesn't decrement the sum on delete.

Comment: Everything is fine, but can it be removed if it is clicked on the delete button and that amount is removed from the total?

Answer (score 0):

below code help you to add logic for sum.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var totle = 0;
  $(".add-row").click(function() {

    var packageid = $('#pack').find(':selected').attr('data-id');
    var itemid = $('#itemname').find(':selected').attr('item-id');
    var itemname = $("#itemname").val();
    var item_price = $("#item_price").val();
    var packs = $("#pack").val();
    var markup = "<tr><td data-id=" + packageid + ">" + packs + "<td item-id=" + itemid + ">" + itemname + "</td><td class='price'>" + item_price + "</td><td><button class='btn btn-danger' id='del'>Delete</button></td></tr>";
    $("table tbody").append(markup);

    totle += parseInt(item_price);
  });

  $("table").on("click", "#del", function() {
    $("table tbody").find('tr td').each(function() {
      $("table").on("click", "#del", function() {
        $(this).parents("tr").remove();
      })
    });
  });

  $('.add-row').click(function() {

    var ids = [];
    $('.table tbody tr').each(function() {
      ids.push({
        packageid: $(this).find('td:nth-child(1)').attr('data-id'),
        itemid: $(this).find('td:nth-child(2)').attr('item-id'),
        item_price: $(this).find('td:nth-child(3)').html(),
      });
    });
    $('#demo').val(JSON.stringify(ids));
    alert("Totle price is : " + totle);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-3">
  <select class="form-control" id="pack" required>

    <option data-id="1" value="test">test</option>

  </select>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3">
  <select class="form-control" id="itemname">

    <option item-id="1" value="test">example</option>

  </select>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3">
  <input type="number" class="form-control" id="item_price" placeholder="Price">
</div>
<div class="col-md-3">
  <button type="button" class="add-row btn btn-success cusb btn-anim"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i><span class="btn-text">Add Item</span></button>
</div>
</form>

<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Package Name</th>
      <th>Item Name</th>
      <th>Item Price</th>
      <th>Delete</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a div with `totalprice` and then please add some jQuery code as mentioned below.

```
var totalprice = item_price;
var currentprice = $("#totalprice").text();
totalprice  = (parseInt(currentprice)  + parseInt(item_price)) ;
$("#totalprice").html(totalprice);
```

Add it in `add` button.

```js
 
 $(".add-row").click(function () {
            var packageid = $('#pack').find(':selected').attr('data-id');
            var itemid = $('#itemname').find(':selected').attr('item-id');
            var itemname = $("#itemname").val();
            var item_price = $("#item_price").val();
            var packs = $("#pack").val();
            var markup = "<tr><td data-id=" + packageid + ">" + packs + "<td item-id=" + itemid + ">" + itemname + "</td><td class='price'>" + item_price + "</td><td><button class='btn btn-danger' id='del'>Delete</button></td></tr>";
            $("table tbody").append(markup);

var totalprice = item_price;
var currentprice = $("#totalprice").text();
totalprice  = (parseInt(currentprice)  + parseInt(item_price)) ;
$("#totalprice").html(totalprice); 

        });

        $("table").on("click", "#del", function () {
            $("table tbody").find('tr td').each(function () {
                $("table").on("click", "#del", function () {
                    $(this).parents("tr").remove();
                })
            });
        });

        $('.add-row').click(function () {

            

            var ids = [];
            $('.table tbody tr').each(function () {
                ids.push({
                    packageid: $(this).find('td:nth-child(1)').attr('data-id'),
                    itemid: $(this).find('td:nth-child(2)').attr('item-id'),
                    item_price: $(this).find('td:nth-child(3)').html(),
                });

            });
            $('#demo').val(JSON.stringify(ids));
        });
```

```html
<form>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <select class="form-control" id="pack" required>
                      
                            <option data-id="1" value="test">test</option>
                       
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <select class="form-control" id="itemname">
                        
                            <option item-id="1" value="test">example</option>
                     
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="item_price" placeholder="Price">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <button type="button" class="add-row btn btn-success cusb btn-anim"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i><span class="btn-text">Add Item</span></button>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <b>Total Price is : </b><span id = "totalprice">0</span>
                </div>
            </form>

            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Package Name</th>
                    <th>Item Name</th>
                    <th>Item Price</th>
                    <th>Delete</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>

                <tbody>

                </tbody>
            </table>
            
             <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```